# What became of John Wick's Ford Mustang?

Tags: john-wick, john-wick-chapter-2

In [*John Wick* (2014)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wick), he's the owner of a Ford Mustang Boss 429:

[image: A picture of John Wick standing near his car with Iosef Tarasov at the gas station in the first movie]

At the beginning of [*John Wick: Chapter 2*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wick%3A_Chapter_2), he went to retrieve the Mustang. And since it got a little roughed up during retrieval, he left it in the hands of Aurelio for repairs (although the latter commented that it will be ready "Christmas... 2030", i.e. it's going to take a really long time).

Later, at the end of the movie, when John Wick's excommunicado is due in 1 hour after Winston's call, Aurelio is among those who received an SMS (whether that means he's affiliated to Continental affairs or just that he's in the business).

We don't get to see the car again in *[John Wick: Chapter 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wick%3A_Chapter_3)*.

Do we have any information as to what became of John Wick's car after the second movie?

Comment: Why are you after John's car even after knowing what happened?

Comment: It's not 2030 yet.  It makes an appearance in John Wick 7.

Comment: Given that Wick was excommunicado, it makes sense that he wouldn't go back for the car. It's a big, recognizable asset in a known location where many might think to look for it (and by extension, him.)  Also, given that he owned the car originally while he was "out of the business" and married, there's a good chance it's actually registered, therefore traceable.  Not some super-secret assassin job with VINs filed off or something.